# CSS box triangle left

Tags: css

I am having trouble getting the triangle left to display as I desire. I would like to make the following snippet to be a triangle left instead of a square tilted 135 degrees. Help is greatly appreciated!

[Codepen snippet](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjpgOY)

```
/*
Like Count Box
*/
.like-count {
    line-height: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
}
.like-count:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left:-7px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-transform:rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(135deg);
}
```

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rotate the pseudo, you can use its borders to make a triangle.

```css
/*
Like Count Box
*/

.like-count {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.like-count:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -11px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
  border-right: 12px solid black;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<div align="center">
  <div class="like-count">33</div>
</div>
```